# treeview vs asp:menu or custom?

Tags: html, asp.net

I'm working on a webapp and I currently have code that takes info from a database and builds a braching menu system with it. Not knowing much about asp menu options types I decided on something a little different. I placed the database info into nodes in a generic tree object, then while traversing the tree, I used HtmlGenericControl and built a few nested  lists to add the menu from the behind code to the html. It worked, but my boss doesnt seem to like it and said I should try an asp:menu or treeview.

I was wondering if there would be some major advantage to scraping my current menu and going with one of the asp types. I thought what I did was pretty efficient and runs at (O)n. But other than maybe saving a bit of real estate by removing my tree simple data structure, I'm not sure what the help of changing the menu system would be...

Comment: Taste (in this case your boss's taste) does play a big part in these things.  Just sayin'.

Answer (score 0):

The main "advantage" to using the ASP.NET menu server control is that it is very straightforward for adding items to the menu, especially if the menu structure is static. It is obvious to anyone that comes across the control what the intent of the control is and it has a pretty intuitive API for adding items to the menu.

Your approach is one that is used for dynamic menu systems and for menus that need to be styled above and beyond what is supported by the ASP.NET menu control. The list approach allows for data to be retrieved server or client-side and is very CSS friendly, which opens up the doors to generating extremely flexible and aesthetically pleasing renderings for menus. It is also very flexible in generating dynamic menus; for example if you have an Admin section to your menu, then hiding this from the ASP.NET menu is not simple and you will wind up with a bunch of conditional logic in your code behind, but if you are building a menu from data as lists, then it is much easier to update the menu via AJAX.

Not saying you or your boss is right, but there is a place and time for both approaches.

Comment: Well one reason I went the "htmlgenericcontrol" route was the style sheet i was given was made for a <ul> structure and it would avoid tinkering with the extensive ccs. Although I'm sure it could have been converted, I hoped it would save some man hours